# HTML Validator Error - Element slider not allowed as child of element body in this context

Tags: html, css, validation

I am creating a webpage and as I am going along, I am checking HTML validator to make sure that I have no errors. I have now created my slideshow.. and have called it slider and have now come accross this error:

Element slider not allowed as child of element body in this context.

I have tried to put the slider within a header tag, and also inside a div, but am still getting the same error message. 
Here is the HTML for my slider:

```
<slider>
  <slide><p>Slide1</p></slide>
  <slide><p>Slide2</p></slide>
  <slide><p>Slide3</p></slide>
  <slide><p>Slide4</p></slide>
</slider>
```

Where do I need to put this so that it doesn't bring up any HTML validation errors?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you used this [validator](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html). Most HTML validators don't recognize [custom HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements), then warnings will always be displayed for them if you just parse the HTML.

If your custom element has been created properly and works as it should, you can simply ignore these warnings.

Otherwise, you can choose to use standard HTML elements and use attributes like classes.

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide"><p>Slide1</p></div>
  <div class="slide"><p>Slide1</p></div>
  <div class="slide"><p>Slide1</p></div>
  <div class="slide"><p>Slide1</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `slider` is not a valid name for a custom HTML element so it doesn't matter if the validation tool supports custom elements or not.

Comment: Thank you, I put my slider within a div with class attributes and this no longer flags up errors within the validator!

Answer (score 0):

[There is no `slider` element in HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#elements-3).

If you are trying to create *some element* to hang JavaScript from, then pick ones in HTML that have the most suitable semantics for what you want to do.

Maybe `ul` and `li` or `main` and `section` or something else. (You can use a class or id to distinguish them from other elements of the same type).